# swift 4 - Can not show pdf in a UIWebView

Tags: swift, swift3, uiwebview

I am working on the new version of swift 4 and i have the next issue, i can not show a ".pdf" on a UIWebView. First i migrated my project to the new version of Swift, then i had to solve the issue of "Set Swift 3 @objc inference to Default", then when i run my project just some of the PDFs i set when i was working on Swift 3 are showing, i added new ones  after upgrade the swift but does not show it on the UIWebView. This is my code to show the pdf files:

```
    func showCarPdf() {

    print(carPdfView!)

    if let pdf = Bundle.main.url(forResource: carPdfView!, withExtension: "pdf", subdirectory: nil, localization: nil)  {
        let req = NSURLRequest(url: pdf)
        webView.loadRequest(req as URLRequest)
    }
}
```

Does any one know whats happend? Why i can only show the files that i set on swift 3 and not the new ones added with the new version. Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: What is `req`? Which steps did you try to debug the code?

Comment: req is the variable request, the problem was that the files wasn`t copy to the "Copy Bundle Resources", thanks to ask and your help!

Comment: I wanted to know the value of `req`, because I saw the possibility that it is not found …

Answer (score 1):

From your question I understand that you are adding new pdf file... right?

If so...
By default when a resource(images, pdfs, etc...) is added in Xcode 9, it is not getting added to Target.

If you add a new resource make sure, it is set to Target as well. Hope you know how to check whether a resource is added to Target. You can also verify whether a resource is added from the 'Copy Bundle Resources"

Comment: Thanks a lot man ! you help me so much, now i can see all pdf. =D i can not vote cuz i dont have the necesary point to do it =(  but i`ll do it when i can

Comment: See if you can accept it as the answer for your question.

Comment: This is same for XCode 9 ( irrespective of Swift version ). Please mark this as accepted answer.